# order Ienumerable<SelectListItem> according to a string array

Tags: arrays, ienumerable, sql-order-by, linq-to-objects, selectlistitem

I need to order an Ienumerable select list with respect to the values in an array 
my code is shown below:

```
model.RequestedSegments = EvaluationServices.GetSegmentlistItems.Where(a => model.RequestedSelectedSegments.Contains(a.Value));
```

where RequestedSegments and RequestedSelectedSegments are members of a model
declared as:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RequestedSegments { get; set; }
public string[] RequestedSelectedSegments { get; set; }
```

Thanks,
suraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following code and it works ok:

```
model.RequestedSegments = from o in model.RequestedSelectedSegments.Select((o, i) => new { Value = o, Index = i }) join f in model.RequestedSegments on o.Value equals f.Value orderby o.Index select f;
```

Comment: 1 up for posting the answer by yourself.